# SQL Server Management Studio 2012 Pivot/Cross Tab Query

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2012 and would like to create a pivot/cross tab query for a table with over 2300 rows.

The table has 5 columns:

```
 - name
 - group
 - status
 - date
 - count
```

There are about 580 distinct names.

Each name is associated to 4 different groups (A, B, C, and D).

Each group has a complete status of yes or no.

A date is associated to each status when completed. Otherwise, status is NULL.

The count column is only applicable to group B and D and is an integer value.

SAMPLE A:

```
name    group  status   date    count
A.A.1     A     yes     5/23    NULL
A.A.1     B     yes     5/27    112
A.A.1     C     yes     6/4     NULL
A.A.1     D     yes     6/15    122
A.B.2     A     yes     5/25    NULL
A.B.2     B     yes     6/1     119
A.B.2     C     no      NULL    NULL
A.B.2     D     no      NULL    NULL
```

I am trying to display the status of each name as the field values across 11 columns :

```
 - name
 - group A
 - group A date
 - group B
 - group B date
 - group B count
 - group C
 - group C date
 - group D
 - group D date
 - group D count
```

The 'name' column would have the 580 distinct names with their corresponding group data across A, B, C, and D.

SAMPLE B:

```
nm      grp_A   A_day   grp_B   B_day   B_ct    grp_C   C_day   grp_D   D_day   D_ct
A.A.1   yes     5/23    yes     5/27    112     yes     6/4     yes     6/15    122
A.B.2   yes     5/25    yes     6/1     119     no      NULL    no      NULL    NULL
```

(*column names have been changed to fit into this question section's format*)

Ultimately, the result should have all 580 distinct names in the first column and its corresponding status for each group, the date of completion (or NULL if it has not been completed yet), and the count for groups B and D.

I've tried using a CASE statement, but it generates the names once for each group, resulting in the original table being spaced out across the 11 coulmns.

SAMPLE C:

```
nm     grp_A    A_day   grp_B   B_day   B_ct    grp_C   C_day   grp_D   D_day   D_ct
A.A.1   yes     5/23                                
A.A.1                    yes    5/27    112         
A.A.1                                             yes   6/4         
A.A.1                                                            yes    6/15    122
A.B.2   yes     5/25                                
A.B.2                    yes    6/1     119         
A.B.2                                             no    NULL            
A.B.2                                                             no    NULL    NULL
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

-- K-moj

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your query I am guessing but if you are trying to PIVOT the data with a CASE expression my suggestion would be to add an aggregate function around the CASE.

```
select
  name,
  max(case when [group] = 'A' then status end) grp_A,
  max(case when [group] = 'A' then date end) A_day,
  max(case when [group] = 'A' then [count] end) A_ct,
  max(case when [group] = 'B' then status end) grp_B,
  max(case when [group] = 'B' then date end) B_day,
  max(case when [group] = 'B' then [count] end) B_ct,
  max(case when [group] = 'C' then status end) grp_C,
  max(case when [group] = 'C' then date end) C_day,
  max(case when [group] = 'C' then [count] end) C_ct,
  max(case when [group] = 'D' then status end) grp_D,
  max(case when [group] = 'D' then date end) D_day,
  max(case when [group] = 'D' then [count] end) D_ct
from yourtable
group by name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c7d19/6).

If you want to use the PIVOT function then you will need to first look at unpivoting the `status`, `date` and `count` columns first, then pivot them in the the final result.

An UNPIVOT is when you convert multiple columns of data into multiple rows.  You can unpivot the `status`, `date` and `count` columns using a variety of methods.  Since you are using SQL Server 2012 you can use CROSS APPLY with a VALUES clause.  The code to convert the columns into rows will be:

```
select name, 
  col = col+'_'+[group], 
  value
from yourtable 
cross apply
(
  values 
    ('grp', status),
    ('day', [date]),
    ('ct', cast([count] as varchar(10)))
) c(col, value)
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c7d19/8). This gives a result:

```
|  NAME |   COL |  VALUE |
| A.A.1 | grp_A |    yes |
| A.A.1 | day_A |   5/23 |
| A.A.1 |  ct_A | (null) |
| A.A.1 | grp_B |    yes |
| A.A.1 | day_B |   5/27 |
| A.A.1 |  ct_B |    112 |
```

Instead of having multiple columns that you want to pivot, you now have all values to be turned into new columns in `value` and the new column names in `col`. You can then apply the PIVOT function so the full code will be similar to the following:

```
select name,
  grp_A, day_A, ct_A,
  grp_B, day_B, ct_B,
  grp_C, day_C, ct_C,
  grp_D, day_D, ct_D
from
(
  select name, 
    col = col+'_'+[group], 
    value
  from yourtable 
  cross apply
  (
    values 
      ('grp', status),
      ('day', [date]),
      ('ct', cast([count] as varchar(10)))
  ) c(col, value)
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (grp_A, day_A, ct_A,
              grp_B, day_B, ct_B,
              grp_C, day_C, ct_C,
              grp_D, day_D, ct_D)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c7d19/7)

Comment: I don't know wha you mean by "unpivoting" my fields.

Comment: @user2712237 `UNPIVOT` is the process of converting multiple columns into rows, see my edit